# How to install gologin libary

Tags: python, selenium

I can't find the name of the GoLogin library on the Internet to download it.

Here is their example code on the site:

```
from sys import platform
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 from gologin import GoLogin

 gl = GoLogin({
     'token': 'yU0token',
     'profile_id': 'yU0Pr0f1leiD',
 })

 if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
     chrome_driver_path = './chromedriver'
 elif platform == "darwin":
     chrome_driver_path = './mac/chromedriver'
 elif platform == "win32":
     chrome_driver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'

 debugger_address = gl.start()
 chrome_options = Options()
 chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", debugger_address)
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)
 driver.get("http://www.python.org")
 assert "Python" in driver.title
 driver.close()
 time.sleep(3)
 gl.stop()
```

and I got an error when running the code in this part:

```
from gologin import GoLogin
```

this is because I haven't downloaded their library, I tried to download it this way

```
pip install gologin
```

but I got this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gologin (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gologin
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

help me pls. I need install this libary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoLogin supports Linux, MacOS and Windows platforms.

Installation
clone or download this repository

`git clone https://github.com/gologinapp/pygologin.git`

for running gologin-selenium.py install selenium

`pip install selenium`

for Selenium need download webdriver

Answer (score -1):

First clone git  repository

```
git clone https://github.com/gologinapp/pygologin.git
```

Next open `File Explorer` and type `%USERPROFILE%` in address bar

You see folder with name `pygologin`, copy `gologin.py` to your folder and try.