# `ERROR: No matching distribution found for gologin' when trying to `pip install gologin`

Tags: python, git, selenium-webdriver, anaconda, gologin

**Reproducible Example**

In Anaconda prompt:

`pip install gologin`

**Issue Description**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gologin (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gologin
```

**Expected Behavior**

Expect the gologin package to install successfully.

**Installed Versions**

Python 3.10.9

Conda 23.3.1

Selenium 4.10.0

**Extra Discription**

So before posting this question, I did a search of this error and found a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540517/how-to-install-gologin-libary). I followed the solution provided in that post (ie. cloning git repository `git clone https://github.com/gologinapp/pygologin.git` in my local device) but I am still getting the same error above.

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong and how do I fix this? Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Looks like the author simply has not made this package available for `pip` installation.

Comment: @John Gordon - Thanks! This is strange because I am following the steps on this page (https://gologin.com/blog/webscraping/web-scraping-reddit) which is provided by gologin and uses `pip install gologin`. Do you know what could be happening.

Comment: Without looking too deeply, I assume that page is just ... wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved. Need to make sure ALL the individual files in `git clone https://github.com/gologinapp/pygologin.git` are the in same directory where all your Python packages are located, rather than just the one file `gologin.py` as hinted in this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540517/how-to-install-gologin-libary) by Naveen.

For Anaconda, the directory where all your Python packages are located looks something like: `..\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`